# NestJS unit testing of service involving transactional Entity Manager

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, transactions, nestjs, typeorm

```
I have a create function on service like this on service.service.ts file

import { Service } from './entity/service.entity';
import { EntityManager } from 'typeorm';


async create(
  transactionalEntityManager: EntityManager,
  data: any
): Promise<Service> {
  return transactionalEntityManager.save(Service, data);
}
```

```
And a POST route like this on service.controller.ts 

import { EntityManager, getConnection } from 'typeorm';
import { Service } from './entity/service.entity';


@Post()
async createService(
  @Body() body: ServiceDto,
  const user = { user_id: 1, company_id: 2 }
): Promise<Service> {
  return getConnection().transaction(async (t: EntityManager) =>
    this.service.create(t, {
      ...body,
      company_id: user.company_id,
      added_by: user.user_id,
    })
  );
}
```

I need to write unit testing for the create function on service.service.ts.
How can i write unit testing for this function?
I got stuck on transaction.

I tried this https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2586
But none of this worked for me.